# Sharing Projects between solutions & source control

Tags: git, tfs, repository, directory-structure

This may be a pretty stupid question, and if it is please point it out. But I'm just trying to improve my knowledge of the best way to structure a source control repository for multiple people and multiple projects with some shared parts. In short I work with a number of vastly different codebases that have shared libraries for some bits that are common across all implementations our company works with (logging, mail sending etc).

The specific scenario I'm questioning is if I have client A project in one repository & client B's project in a second repository then a set of 'tools' in a third repository what is the best way to share the code and still keep the repositories separate?

In an ideal world we want to be able to open Client A's project and see/edit/check in the code of the 'tools' and the same in Client B's. Currently I'm managing this through just having a second instance of Visual Studio running and manually copying and updating DLLS when changes are made but I feel like there must be a better way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question in one word: NuGet.

What you should be doing is turning any shared components into NuGet packages that are published to a NuGet feed, and are referenced by any projects that need them. Modern versions of TFS both VSTS have native Package Management feeds (available as an extension). However, a package management feed can be as simple as a file share somewhere on your network.

Answer (score 0):

> In an ideal world we want to be able to open Client A's project and see/edit/check in the code of the 'tools' and the same in Client B's.

You can achieve this by having one solution. I know you mentioned that you keep the code in 3 repos, but maybe this isn't necessary.

Having a single solution means that if you change the code in 'tools' you immediately see the impact on both client's (and can run tests for both clients to confirm that the changes did not break A or B.

With a single solution you also see the changes to all files in a single place  which reduces the possibility of forgetting to check something in.

Finally, you can combine the 3 into one until the code it Tools stabilises and then release it (via NuGet, for example).

I think the decision between a NuGet pacakge for Tools and single solution should be based on how big Tools are and how often the code in Tools changes.

Other options:

- Duplicate the code in Tools and have the sources in both A and B repos
- Move some code from Tools to A and B and leave some in Tools and create a NuGet - this could work if the new Tools doesn't change often

Comment: One solution for both client projects wouldn't be feasible in this instance due to the nature of the clients & the codebases. But I like the idea! I think Nuget is seeming like the way to go

Comment: Please note that you can a have a local NuGet repo that is just a folder. It doesn't have to be fancy.

Comment: I'm actually thinking of deploying to a password protected azure instance for ease of access anywhere in the world. But thanks for the advice